# Grav CMS | MaterializeCSS | How can we use Materialize CSS with Grav form plugin?

Tags: html, css, forms, materialize, grav

How can we change the look (CSS) of the included Form-plugin generated form page?

I included my own CSS for the rest of the site, but my Markdown contact.md page looks bad, and I'm using Materializecss framework.

I managed to include Markdown into HTML for other pages, but Forms plugin makes its own HTML for the form so I can't put form fields inside my HTML like that.

Do I need to delete CSS from somewhere which is Form plugin related, change default HTML of Plugin formating somewhere, or do I need to give some classes to the Markdown file of the form fields somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late in answer, but the answer actually comes down to you creating custom templates, one for each field that you want to override. It's a bit tedious, but can be done.

I'm actually using the MaterializeCSS library on my own webpage, and have done some of the work on my [github](https://github.com/jacobm001/grav-theme-materialize-css/tree/master/templates). Take a look at the `forms` folder under templates to see how it works.